# T-SQL for merging data from one table to another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's say there are 2 tables Table1 { ID, Name, Other } and Table2 { ID, Name, Other }. Both of them have identical records with the same IDs except that in Table1 all Name values are NULL. How can I import Name values from Table2 to Table1 using T-SQL (SQL Server 2008)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Update Table1
Set Table1.Name = Table2.Name
From
Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew it should be simple :)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the MERGE command, which is like the UPSERT that you've probably read about elsewhere. Here's a [quick article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3739131/UPSERT-Functionality-in-SQL-Server-2008.htm) about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Name = Table2.Name
FROM Table2
WHERE Table1.Id = Table2.Id
--AND Table1.Name IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Just join the tables and update:

```
update t1
set [Name] = t2.Name
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.ID
```